# How to operate dataset from paperswithcode.com?

Tags: dataset, api

I'm trying to use IG-3.5B-17k dataset from paperswithcode.com, but I can't figure out how to do that exactly.
How to do it? I guess I need to use this site API? Am I even able to use this dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is specified in the [dataset description in paperswithcode.com](https://paperswithcode.com/dataset/ig-3-5b-17k) (emphasis mine):

> IG-3.5B-17k is an **internal** Facebook AI Research dataset for training image classification models. It consists of hashtags for up to 3.5 billion public Instagram images.

So the dataset is not public.

In [the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.00932v1.pdf), however, the authors argue that the images and their hashtags are "visible" in Instagram:

> Our datasets have two nice properties: public visibility and simplicity. By using publicly accessible images, the data used in our experiments is
> visible to everyone. To see what it looks like, the images are browsable by hashtag at https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/ followed by a specific hashtag;
> for example https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/brownbear shows images tagged with #brownbear. Our data is also taken from the “wild”, essentially as-is, with minimal effort to sanitize it. This makes the dataset construction process particularly simple and transparent.

I understand that they are saying "you can go and query Instagram yourself" to see the images in the dataset, but I don't think this is actually practical or even [allowed in their terms of service](https://www.facebook.com/help/instagram/1188470931252371).